# getting typeerror when trying to download an image via urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, urllib

im trying to make a function for my discord bot that will download an image someone posts. heres the code:

```
import urllib.request as ulib

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'

def discord_image_downloading(url):
    req = ulib.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = ulib.urlopen(req)
    ulib.urlretrieve(resp)

discord_image_downloading('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/416027245572915230/417844317009477653/7BD311E9A2ADD8B844BCDEDFD491261EFD0EEF90020C2C6421pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.png')
```

and heres the error i keep getting:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

The `urllib.request.urlretrieve` function takes a URL, as the name implies. You're passing it a response instead. Since the response object can't be read as a string, it gives the error you're seeing.

Since the `urlretrieve` function does all the work for you, you don't need to muck about with `Request`s or anything. Just call `ulib.urlretrieve(image_url, destination_filename)`.

EDIT: If you do want to use the `Request` object, then you don't need to use `urlretrieve` at all.

```
with ulib.urlopen(req) as resp:
    data = resp.read()
```

`data` now contains all the bytes of your image, which can be written out to a (binary-mode) file or sent to an image processing function of your choice.

(I'm using the response as a context manager here, which ensures it's closed when you're done.)

However, for anything more complicated than simple image downloading, a higher-level package like "Requests" will be your friend.

Comment: only problem is when i try to download the image that way, it gives me a 403 error, so would there be anyway to add in headers to the urlretrieve function?